# Show line to the right of text in plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

By default, tikz shows the text in a legend to the right of the line as shown in the picture below.
[image: sin(x) and cos(x) with legend]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            legend cell align=right
        ]
        \addplot [blue, domain=0:360] {sin(x)};
        \addlegendentry{sin and some other text}

        \addplot [red, domain=0:360] {cos(x)};
        \addlegendentry{cos}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In this case, I want the text to be right aligned as is shown in the image. To me this would look better if the red and blue lines were displayed on the right of the text. Is there any way to achieve this?

P.S. this is my first post on SE, so please let me know if there is any way to improve my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There sure is! See the `legend plot pos` key on page 209 of the v1.12 manual. It takes the values `legend plot pos=left|right|none`, where you pick one of the options that you want. P.S. You don't need to load both `tikz` and `pgfplots` since `pgfplots` loads `tikz` already. In addition, you should set the compatibility of `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            legend cell align=right,
            legend plot pos=right,
        ]
        \addplot [blue, domain=0:360] {sin(x)};
        \addlegendentry{sin and some other text}

        \addplot [red, domain=0:360] {cos(x)};
        \addlegendentry{cos}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and the helpfull hints! I also noticed that you can use a comma at the end of the last argument (e.g. of \begin{axis}). That will save lots of editing when copy-pasting :).

Comment: @Octaviour Oh, yes, that's a habit I have from using version control. That way when I add lines in the options, I only change 1 line in the version control instead of two (adding the comma + the new option).